Why KivyMD adding to icons and to check boxes in the lest item
I followed the Kivymd 1.1.1 docs for how to make a list and add an item to it, and I spent days trying to fix the it, but I did not find any solution. That's my code. What's the problem with the code?

from kivymd.app import MDApp 
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.list import IRightBodyTouch, ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.pickers import MDDatePicker
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class TaskScreen(Screen):pass

class AddTask(Screen):pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):pass

class ListItemWithCheckbox(ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem):
    """'''Custom list item.'''
    The list item will be added to the task list"""
    icon = StringProperty("android")

class RightCheckbox(IRightBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
    '''Custom right container.'''


class TasksApp(MDApp):
    # def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    #     super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def add_task(self,title, task, date):
        title = self.root.ids.add_task.ids.title.text
        task = self.root.ids.add_task.ids.task.text
        date = self.root.ids.add_task.ids.date.text
        task_item =ListItemWithCheckbox(text=title,
                                        secondary_text=task,
                                        tertiary_text=date,
                                        )
        self.root.ids.task_screen.ids.container.add_widget(task_item)
        
        self.clean_fields(title,task,date)

    def clean_fields(self,title,task,date):
        self.root.ids.add_task.ids.title.text = ''
        self.root.ids.add_task.ids.task.text = ''
        self.root.ids.add_task.ids.date.text = ''
    
    def open_date_picker(self):
        date_dialog = MDDatePicker()
        date_dialog.bind(on_save=self.on_save)
        date_dialog.open()
    
    def on_save(self, instance, value, date_range):
        value = value.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')
        self.root.ids.add_task.ids.date.text = str(value)
    
    def remove_item(self,task_item):
        self.root.ids.task_screen.ids.container.remove_widget(task_item)
        
    
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Teal'
        return Builder.load_file('tasks.kv')


TasksApp().run()


and the kv file:

#: import CardTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.CardTransition
#: import datetime datetime
# :set date_text datetime.now().strftime('%A %d %B %Y')


Manager:
    id:sm
    TaskScreen:
        id: task_screen
    AddTask:
        id: add_task

<TaskScreen>:
    name: 'task_screen'
    MDFloatLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        MDLabel:
            text: "[size=40][u][b]Tasks[/b][/u][/size]"
            color: 'teal'
            markup:True
            halign: 'center'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.95}
        MDLabel:
            id: date_now
            text:str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('[b][size=25]Today: [/size][/b][b][size=20]%A %d %B %Y -%I:%M[/size][/b]'))
            color: 'teal'
            markup:True
            halign: 'center'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.88}

    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: container

    MDFloatingActionButton:
        elevation:3
        icon: 'plus-outline'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.09}
        on_release:
            # app.root.transition.direction = 'left'
            app.root.transition = CardTransition(mode='pop')
            app.root.current = 'add_task'

<AddTask>:
    name: 'add_task'

    MDLabel:
        text: "[size=40][u][b]Add Task[/b][/u][/size]"
        color: 'teal'
        markup:True
        halign: 'center'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.95}

    MDLabel:
        id: date_now
        text:str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('[b][size=25]Today: [/size][/b][b][size=20]%A %d %B %Y - %I:%M[/size][/b]'))
        color: 'teal'
        markup:True
        halign: 'center'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.88}
    MDLabel:
        id: date
        text: '[u][size=15]___[/size][/u]'
        color: 'teal'
        markup:True
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.65,'center_y': 0.75}
    MDIconButton:
        icon:'calendar-multiselect'
        icon_size:'48sp'
        theme_icon_color: "Custom"
        icon_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.75,'center_y': 0.75}
        on_release: app.open_date_picker()

    MDLabel:
        text: "[size=20][u][b]Title[/b][/u][/size]"
        color: 'teal'
        markup: True
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.65,'center_y': 0.6}

    MDTextField:
        id: title
        pos_hint:{"center_x": 0.5,'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint_x: 0.7
        max_text_length: 20
        font_size: 20
        bold:True

    MDLabel:
        text: "[size=20][u][b]Enter Task[/b][/u][/size]"
        color: 'teal'
        markup:True
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.65,'center_y': 0.4}

    MDTextField:
        id: task
        pos_hint:{"center_x": 0.5,'center_y': 0.3}
        size_hint_x: 0.7
        max_text_length:60
        font_size:19
        bold:True

    MDRaisedButton:
        text:'Save'
        pos_hint:{"center_x": 0.72,'center_y': 0.15}
        on_release:
            app.add_task(title, task, date)
            app.root.transition = CardTransition(mode='pop')
            app.root.current = 'task_screen'

    MDIconButton:
        icon: 'arrow-u-right-top'
        icon_size:'48sp'
        theme_icon_color: "Custom"
        icon_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y': 0.15}
        on_release:
            # app.root.transition.direction = 'right'
            app.root.transition = CardTransition(mode='pop')
            app.root.current = 'task_screen'
            app.clean_fields(title, task, date)

<ListItemWithCheckbox>:
    id: task_item


    RightCheckbox:
        id : checbox

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: 'trash-can-outline'
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: 'teal' #1, 0, 0, 1
        on_release:app.remove_item(task_item)


and the pic for the app to icons and to check boxes
search on the web reading docs try to change the list items and positions of widgets and check for any code mistakes or typo ....

Not sure if this is the answer, but the line in your build() method:
return Builder.load_file('tasks.kv')

Is loading tasks.kv for the second time. That kv file is loaded automatically by the App because of its name (see the documentation). You should either change the name of your kv file, or just eliminate the call to Build.load_file().

thank you very much, it works fine and the error has been fixed
